# Как выполнить код в системе Azure?

Tags: azure

Было дано задание выполнить простой код например "Hello, world!" на облачной платформе Azure.
Подробной инструкции я к сожалению не смог найти, могли бы вы объяснить поэтапно как это делается.
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов развертывания приложений в облаке.

Основной вопрос — это то, где вам хочется или требуется развернуть приложение: на виртуальной машине, в контейнере или в решении PaaS (платформа как услуга).

С **виртуальными машинами** вы находитесь в мире, аналогичном локальной или классической среде центра обработки данных. Azure предоставляет набор предварительно настроенных виртуальных машин с основной операционной системой (Windows или Linux), которые вам необходимо настроить и обслуживать.

**Контейнеры** предоставляют почти такие же широкие возможности контроля, как и виртуальные машины, но требуют меньше усилий. Вы можете установить собственную виртуальную машину Java или другое специализированное ПО, и ваши контейнеры смогут работать как локально, так и в любой среде поставщика облачных служб.

Решение **платформа как услуга** требует минимальных усилий для обслуживания и эксплуатации, так как эти обязанности ложатся на плечи поставщика облачных служб. Поставщик своевременно устанавливает обновления операционной системы (ОС), исправления Java, а также обеспечивает безопасность и соответствие требованиям. Поэтому такой вариант более безопасен и экономичен. Он также имеет некоторые функции масштабируемости, которые позволят вашему приложению лучше адаптироваться к потребностям клиентов. Это также повышает производительность при нагрузке и снижает затраты при уменьшении объема трафика.

Я бы порекомендовала почитать и пройти данный бесплатный курс от Майкрософта. Он как раз по вашему запросу:

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/learn/paths/java-on-azure/